# Dataframe containing value 0 should be removed or replaced?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, python, pandas, numpy

I have a question that mostly I get stuck at. I was looking at the data for diabetes patients and found that most of the rows have 0 values under most of their columns. Reference for the url

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data

The dataframe is listed as under.

```
  Pregnancies  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin  BMI  \
0          6      148             72             35        0  33.6   
1          1       85             66             29        0  26.6   
2          8      183             64              0        0  23.3   
3          1       89             66             23       94  28.1   
4          0      137             40             35      168  43.1   

DiabetesPedigreeFunction  Age  Outcome  
0.627                     50        1  
0.351                     31        0  
0.672                     32        1  
0.167                     21        0  
2.288                     33        1
```

If I wanted to remove the value that are **0**, should I replace the **0** value with the mean or medium or should I remove the value **0** from every rows of the columns. I know if I make any mistake in removing or updating the value it will make my model rejected.